# using purrr with expand.grid to loop over formulas for a t.test while conditioning on another variable

Tags: r, purrr

I'd like to make some purrr code more concise. I have a df with one dependent variable (y) and 4 independent variables (x1, x2, x3, x4). I also have one conditioning variable that takes 2 levels (z, is either zero or 1). I'd like to run 8 t-tests: y ~ x1 [z==0], y ~ x2 [z==0] ... y ~ x1 [z==1], y ~ x2 [z==1] etc. I'd like to return a single dataframe with the tidy tests stacked on top of each other.

I really want to generalize this method for more combinations of predictors, so building a formula and using expand.grid seems like the best way to go. I'd also like to use a combination of dplyr/purrr/broom to do this. The following works, but I'm wondering, is there a way to get everything into a single pipe?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), x2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), x3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), x4 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), z = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

ivs <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")
med <- c(0, 1)

models <- expand.grid(ivs, med) %>% mutate(frm = paste0("y ~ ", Var1)) 

formula <- models$frm   
cond <- models$Var2

models <-  map2_df(formula, cond, ~tidy(t.test(as.formula(.x), data=df[df$z==.y,])))
```

I'm wondering why, for instance, doesn't the following work?

```
models <- expand.grid(ivs, med) %>% mutate(frm = paste0("y ~ ", Var1)) %>% map2_df(.$frm, .$Var2, ~tidy(t.test(as.formula(.x), data=df[df$z==.y,])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st code worked because `formula` & `cond` were considered lists by `map2_df`. However it wasn't the case when you put them in the `pipe` that created a data frame. You cannot do `.x$frm` or `.x$Var2`.

To make it work, you can use `pmap_df` to loop through each row of the data frame created inside the `pipe` and refer to the order of the columns by using `..1, ..2, ..3` and so on

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 x2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 x3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 x4 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 z = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

ivs <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")
med <- c(0, 1)

models <- expand.grid(ivs, med) %>% 
  mutate(frm = paste0("y ~ ", Var1)) 

formula <- models$frm   
cond <- models$Var2

models <-  map2_df(formula, cond, ~ tidy(t.test(as.formula(.x), data = df[df$z == .y, ])))

# using pmap to loop through the columns of the data frame (essentially list of columns)
models2 <- expand.grid(ivs, med) %>% 
  mutate(frm = paste0("y ~ ", Var1)) %>% 
  pmap_df(., ~ tidy(t.test(as.formula(..3), data = df[df$z == ..2, ])))
models2

#>     estimate    estimate1   estimate2  statistic    p.value parameter
#> 1  0.2039970 -0.002158780 -0.20615579  0.6372003 0.52724597  44.68250
#> 2 -0.4488714 -0.341650359  0.10722106 -1.4646944 0.15052718  41.56782
#> 3 -0.3016148 -0.246980034  0.05463477 -0.9189260 0.36427350  35.86492
#> 4  0.2601315 -0.004184604 -0.26431615  0.8668975 0.39031605  47.94586
#> 5 -0.2303647 -0.099116913  0.13124775 -0.8420942 0.40422649  44.61732
#> 6  0.5992558  0.385767243 -0.21348854  2.0517453 0.04957898  28.21589
#> 7  0.5027880  0.243581778 -0.25920622  1.9502349 0.05803462  40.84076
#> 8 -0.2735021 -0.101687239  0.17181481 -0.9498541 0.34888013  34.04935
#>       conf.low conf.high                  method alternative
#> 1 -0.440936247 0.8489303 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 2 -1.067524893 0.1697821 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 3 -0.967373762 0.3641441 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 4 -0.343220972 0.8634841 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 5 -0.781476516 0.3207472 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 6  0.001181137 1.1973304 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 7 -0.017929386 1.0235054 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#> 8 -0.858637554 0.3116335 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided

identical(models, models2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Created on 2018-03-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Excellent, I understand the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a column with `mutate` and then `unnest` to make the `map2` to work

```
expand.grid(ivs, med) %>% 
     mutate(frm = paste0("y ~ ", Var1),  
     models = map2(frm, Var2, 
             ~tidy(t.test(as.formula(.x), data=df[df$z==.y,])))) %>% 
     unnest
```

-output

```
#Var1 Var2    frm     estimate   estimate1    estimate2   statistic   p.value parameter   conf.low conf.high                  method alternative
#1   x1    0 y ~ x1 -0.114744071  0.04200976  0.156753835 -0.45597353 0.6507153  42.78050 -0.6223126 0.3928245 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#2   x2    0 y ~ x2  0.172546432  0.17607867  0.003532233  0.70766872 0.4834670  38.01821 -0.3210412 0.6661340 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#3   x3    0 y ~ x3 -0.030023506  0.08421478  0.114238290 -0.12359928 0.9022370  40.96801 -0.5206019 0.4605549 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#4   x4    0 y ~ x4  0.227916033  0.23737142  0.009455385  0.82946231 0.4139292  27.71931 -0.3351932 0.7910253 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#5   x1    1 y ~ x1 -0.296263674 -0.36088080 -0.064617122 -1.03186671 0.3071431  49.56892 -0.8730740 0.2805466 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#6   x2    1 y ~ x2 -0.006999223 -0.20785051 -0.200851283 -0.02445166 0.9805852  52.39709 -0.5812929 0.5672944 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#7   x3    1 y ~ x3 -0.408614666 -0.40526169  0.003352971 -1.45546811 0.1515498  52.00764 -0.9719677 0.1547384 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
#8   x4    1 y ~ x4  0.142488951 -0.13990134 -0.282390287  0.48945275 0.6267376  48.28189 -0.4427566 0.7277345 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

---

to make this more `tidyverse` syntax, we can replace the `expand.grid` with `crossing`

```
crossing(Var1 = ivs, Var2 = med) %>%
    mutate(frm = paste0("y ~ ", Var1),  
    models = map2(frm, Var2, 
         ~tidy(t.test(as.formula(.x), data=df[df$z==.y,])))) %>% 
    unnest
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 13
#  Var1   Var2 frm    estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                  alternative
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <fctr>                  <fctr>     
#1 x1     0    y ~ x1 -0.115      0.0420   0.157     -0.456    0.651      42.8   -0.622     0.393 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#2 x1     1.00 y ~ x1 -0.296     -0.361   -0.0646    -1.03     0.307      49.6   -0.873     0.281 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#3 x2     0    y ~ x2  0.173      0.176    0.00353    0.708    0.483      38.0   -0.321     0.666 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#4 x2     1.00 y ~ x2 -0.00700   -0.208   -0.201     -0.0245   0.981      52.4   -0.581     0.567 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#5 x3     0    y ~ x3 -0.0300     0.0842   0.114     -0.124    0.902      41.0   -0.521     0.461 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#6 x3     1.00 y ~ x3 -0.409     -0.405    0.00335   -1.46     0.152      52.0   -0.972     0.155 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#7 x4     0    y ~ x4  0.228      0.237    0.00946    0.829    0.414      27.7   -0.335     0.791 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
#8 x4     1.00 y ~ x4  0.142     -0.140   -0.282      0.489    0.627      48.3   -0.443     0.728 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
```